# foreignObject browser compatibility

Tags: svg, cross-browser, compatibility, microsoft-edge

I want to use [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) in an svg, to (conditionally) render an input field. In the MDN docs about foreignObject (see link above), a compatibility table shows a question mark on edge.

In other words - could someone with a windows machine and an Edge browser please be so kind and see if the following jsFiddle renders an input in the red circle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sventies/p2osc5nt/

```
<svg width="100%" height="500"> 
  <circle cx="120" cy="120" r="100" fill="red" />
  <foreignObject x="50" y="40" width="180" height="180">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input />
      </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you need to do that sort of thing, you can create a Wn10 VM legally and for free by using VirtualBox and downloading a Win10 ISO from MS. You don't even need to activate it with a serial number, it will remain functional probably forever. 
SO is not really the place to ask others to try your samples (although I did and it looks the same under Edge as it does under Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code in Edge on Windows 10 both from the jsFiddle and from my local. Here are the results:
Chrome: [image]
Edge: [image]

The white box is indeed an input box.

Note: On local, I had to add the SVG namespace ( `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`) to have the circle render. Not so in jsFiddle.